# How to implement a message handler similar to Android, but in normal Java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, messaging, nxt

Problem: I have to connect a Lego NXT robot to an Android device via bluetooth. The NXT is running leJos, so I can use normal Java code on it. Those devices will send and receive messages from each other. Now, the Android part is clear to me, i did similar things in the past using the Message and Handler classes of Android API.

Is there a similar API in standard Java and how to use it?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10702622/1509025) related thread, but couldn't figure out how it should work.
Then I found the [Java Message Service API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Ecommerce/jms/) (JMS) from Java EE. Could this be useful?
I am just not sure if Java EE stuff will run on that NXT brick...

Answer (score 0):

What if you find `Handler.java` and `Looper.java` and `Message.java` and whatever else is needed in the Android sources and adapt it for your needs? Not sure about licensing policy though.

Comment: Licensing won't be a problem, but I'm not sure how much those classes rely on the Android system... will try to find the sources. Any opinion on JMS? thx

Comment: @Sven Menschner I really don't know, I thought JMS is something entirely different

Comment: you were right, JMS is something completely different. I found out that leJos is based on Java ME, and a lot of components used by those Android classes are not supported... I really don't know how to achieve it now.